# Which alternative can i use instead EOF in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to make a webform in Asp.net. I am checking till EOF is false using while loop. How can i achieve the same using C#. My vb code is.

```
While READER.EOF = False

                Done(count) = myReader("Name").Value
                count += 1
                READER.MoveNext()
End While
```

Things i have tried in my C# code.

```
while (myReader.Read())
  {                 
   Done[count] = myReader["Name"].ToString();
   count += 1;                
  }
```

I am aware that myReader.read() will automatically move to the next record. Now my question is how can i check till the End of file is false in my C# code. 
`while (myReader.Read() == false).` Is it the right way ?. I am not able to get it. Please help!

Comment: I think `while(myReader.Read())` will loop until end of file is reached, so no need to add anything to it

Comment: Is this a SqlDataReader (I'm assuming SQL but could be any IDataReader)

Comment: Your VB code looks suspicious - have you ever tested that with an empty result set?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you're referring to a data reader**

You don't want to test the equality with false. What `Read()` will do for you is read the current record and advance to the next returning true if there are more records and false when it has reached the end.

Reading the data will require a `GetString()` or `GetInt32` depending on it's type. Alternatively, you can use an index as follows `myReader[0]` or `myReader["Name"]` to get it as an object and cast it to the type you want although I'd recommend the former.

You can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) for details on the `Read()` method.

**Update: Including VB code**

The way to do that in VB is as follows:

```
Do While myReader.Read()
    Done(count) = myReader("Name").Value
    count += 1
End While
```